# Await Rx Observable result in Controller never produces any result

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive

I have a Web API Controller with a POST method that I want to use to refresh my data and return it. My Crawler fetchs HTML, parses it, and emits a value to SourceObservable, contained the parsed data. It's working fine once `Repository.Save(accreditationData)` is actually saving. But returning this `accreditationDataObservable` isn't working, so my Action never ends the response and Postman looks like waiting indefinitely:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<AccreditationData<AllMantainedTableRow>> Post()
{
    var savedSubject = new Subject<bool>();

    AllMantainedCrawler.SourceObservable.Subscribe(accreditationData => {
        Repository.Save(accreditationData);
        savedSubject.OnNext(true);
    });

    var accreditationDataObservable = AllMantainedCrawler.SourceObservable.TakeUntil(savedSubject.AsObservable());

    AllMantainedCrawler.SourceSubject.OnNext(new Uri("my URL here"));

    return await accreditationDataObservable;
}
```

Also I tried `Take(1)` instead `TakeUntil` and also returning `ToTask()` instead of observable, but got same result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using an Observable instead of a Task? does that impact other places?

Comment: The Crawler has this Observable and this is the way to listen to fresh data. So I want to setup subscribe, request crawling with `OnNext` and return the first value the observable emits

Answer (score 2):

> AllMantainedCrawler.SourceSubject.OnNext(new Uri("my URL here"));

This line forces the crawler to emit. Therefore the `savedSubject` will also emit.

> var accreditationDataObservable = AllMantainedCrawler.SourceObservable.TakeUntil(savedSubject.AsObservable());

if the saveSubject emits the above line complete the `accreditationDataObservable` but in the last line you try to await an already completed accreditationDataObservable.

if your remove the OnNext line and let the crawler emit you can await the accreditationDataObservable as long as it completes.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever call an `OnNext` inside a `Subscribe`. There is always a way to avoid it.

With your code it seems that this would be the equivalent without the `OnNext`:

```
public async Task<AccreditationData<AllMantainedTableRow>> Post()
{
    var accreditationDataObservable = AllMantainedCrawler.SourceObservable.Take(1).Do(x => Repository.Save(x));
    AllMantainedCrawler.SourceSubject.OnNext(new Uri("my URL here"));
    return await accreditationDataObservable;
}
```

However, I can't understand what the `AllMantainedCrawler.SourceSubject.OnNext(new Uri("my URL here"));` is doing here as you haven't provided enough detail in the question. If you can provide complete code I think I can help you.

---

As mentioned, I don't know how the `SourceSubject` relates to the `SourceObservable`, but If I can assume that `accreditationData` is just the `Uri` then this will work:

```
public async Task<AccreditationData<AllMantainedTableRow>> Post()
{
    return await Observable.Start(() => Repository.Save(new Uri("my URL here")));
}
```